# Переменные из CSV файла передаются не верно в BASH скрипте

Tags: linux, ubuntu, парсер, bash, csv

Хочу массово создать сигнатуры пользователей на почтовом сервере Zimbra. Мой код считывает построчно данные из csv файла, берет нужные мне первую переменную: ИМЯ, и вторую - email. И по идее при каждой итерации создает сигнатуру(подпись) пользователю. Упираюсь в ошибку что нет такого аккаунта, хотя пользователи эти есть точно. Но если запускать скрипт с параметрами - все работает. В чем подвох?

[image: Возвращаемая ошибка]

```
while IFS=, read -r NAME EMAIL;

do

zmprov csig $EMAIL !NEW-signature zimbraPrefMailSignatureHTML 'HTML подпись как бы)'

done < variables.csv
```

Уже голову сломал, вродь простой код!

Comment: Возможно `variables.csv` содержит символ возврата картеки `\r`, попробуйте передать данные в цикл `done< <(sed 's/\r//g' variables.csv)`

Comment: echo/print — лучший друг программиста. `$ while IFS=, read -r NAME EMAIL; echo -n "$EMAIL" | hd; done < variables.csv` и посмотрите глазами, что не так.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Всем спасибо за коменты! Уже не стал париться, на питоне написал скрипт передающий переменные для запуска скрипта bash.

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем в такой конструкции `bash`. Пишите уже всё на Питоне, **по-человечески**.